# How to store sub-query into variable in laravel queries?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is my query, I want to save the total_cost into a variable so that I can use that value for further calculations. But its not working, how can achieve this or there is any another way ?
I am getting empty value in `final_amount` when i print it.

```
DB::table('user')->select(
            DB::raw("user.id,  user.name, 
            @variable := COUNT(DISTINCT job.total_cost) AS total_cost,
            @variable * 2.3 as final_amount
    "))
        ->leftJoin('job','job.code','user.id')
        ->groupBy('job.id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Why not use eloquent?

Comment: you of course try use in-build PHP function `extract`

Comment: My Actual query is pretty big, this is just a part of it. If you can show me how can i use eloquent on above query that will be also helpfull. My main concern is to avoid writting ```COUNT(DISTINCT job.total_cost)```  again and again. Any method is acceptable if i achieve that

Comment: @ВасилийПивоваров I dont know, how can i use extract in this query

Comment: To avoid writing COUNT(DISTINCT(job.total_cost)) you can write in class model `scope` , check official documentation about scope